# I am having this Issue when trying to deploy my API to heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, knex.js

I've installed the PostgreSQL add-on from Heroku, but I am using Knex.js on my backend, as I was using before with SQLite and I'm having the following error.

I was building a backend for a site and mobile app and tried to deploy it to Heroku, when in development I was using SQLite, but figured that since I was using Knex.js, I could easily transfer to Postgres add-on from Heroku. I am running into this problem, when running `knex migrate:latest` on `postbuild`.

```
no such file or directory, scandir '/tmp/build_46fb7aa66e7e3cea06d2f04a21ad9249/migrations'
```

Here is my knex file:

```
// Update with your config settings.

module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
      filename: './src/database/db.sqlite'
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: './src/database/migrations'
    },
    useNullAsDefault: true
  },


  test: {
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
      filename: './src/database/test.sqlite'
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: './src/database/migrations'
    },
    useNullAsDefault: true
  },

  staging: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'my_db',
      user:     'username',
      password: 'password'
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  },

  production: {
    client: 'pg',
    debug: true,
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    },
    ssl: true
  }

};
```

and my connections

```
const knex = require('knex')
const configuration = require('../../knexfile')

const config = process.env.NODE_ENV


const connection = knex(configuration[config])


module.exports = connection
```

The migrations for test and development are working just fine

I don't know either if this is going to work after that, so if anyone has any experience I could use any help

Comment: "but figured that since I was using knex, I could easily transfer to Postgre add-on from heroku"—bad idea. _Always_ develop using the same database you're targeting in production. Even with a library like knex, database engines aren't drop-in replacements for each other.

Comment: Why are you not providing a migrations directory in your production configuration?

Comment: Oh, it might be it, I'm gonna look it up

Comment: It worked! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Heroku can't find your migrations.

Your production configuration doesn't appear to contain a migrations directory. Try adding it, e.g.

```js
  production: {
    client: 'pg',
    debug: true,
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations',
      directory: './src/database/migrations'  // <-- here
    },
    ssl: true
  }
```

> when in development I was using SQLite, but figured that since I was using Knex.js, I could easily transfer to Postgres add-on from Heroku

I urge you to use the same database in both development and production. Database engines aren't drop-in replacements for each other, even if you are using something like Knex.